# Devise custom mailer using Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'd like to use a Sendgrid template to send users their welcome email when they signup for my site.  I've checked out: [Devise's How-to Use customer mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer) and already done the first few steps, however, I'm stuck on where to put the `confirmation_instructions` method since I need to be able to put in some custom information and substitution variables to pass through.  I'm also using the devise generated controller `controllers/users/...`

This is what I have so far:

**Custom Class: models/devise_mailer.rb**

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

added: `config.mailer = "DeviseMailer"`

Now from here, I'm supposed to do something like below, but I don't know where to put that.  Do I need to make a custom controller?  If so, how do I make sure new user registrations use the method?:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
  super
end
```

Am I way off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it here:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def self.confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    new(:confirmation_instructions, record, token, opts)
  end
end
```

(Note changed method)

And then call it wherever you want from any controller like this:

```
current_user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... so, oddly, there isn't a `def create` method in my devise registrations controller.  So, when a user signs up, what drives it?  Is the controller somewhere else or backed into a devise script somewhere else?

Comment: @Godzilla74 The registration controller is located in the Devise itself. We only generate another `registration_controller.rb` file if we want to override the base functionality which is in the Devise. A bit harder to see it by yourself, other then digging into the Devise, but many users have already done this, so that's why so many different resources telling how to do something with it.